# Is it possible to create a vertical menu bar in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

Is it possible to create a vertical menu bar in Primefaces?

I am used to pure AJax frameworks like Ext-JS that make this simple but so far I have not seen such a component in PF.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called tieredMenu. See:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/tieredMenu.xhtml

Answer (score 2):

You need search TieredMenu in primefaces showcase.